# Haskell List of Data Type Sorting

Tags: list, sorting, haskell, types

I got a custom Data type named Student which has marks for 2 subjects. I have created a function named average that calculates the average of two. All work fine.

My question is how can I sort list of students by their average?

```
data Student = Student
    {studentName :: String,
     subject1 :: Double,
     subject2 :: Double} deriving (Show)

average :: Student -> Double
average (Student _ sub1 sub2) = (sub1 + sub2) / 2

students :: [Student]
students = [Student "Dave"  50.0  40.0,
            Student "Joe"   65.0  90.0,
            Student "Ann"   75.0  82.0]
```

P.S. I am a beginner in Haskell and don't know whether its got a
 inbuilt average function but I prefer if I can sort my list in similar
 way without using inbuilt average function (if it is there) as this
 small test solution to be use with a different type of function
 instead average.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy)

studentsSortedByAverage = sortBy (compare `on` average) students
```

Note that those are backticks around `on`, not single quotes.

Here are links to docs for [`sortBy`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3asortBy) and [`on`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Function.html#v%3aon).

---

If you are using an old compiler that doesn't come with `Data.Function`, here is the definition of `on`:

```
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
(.*.) `on` f = \x y -> f x .*. f y
```

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks I get a error saying "Can't find imported module Data.Function" when I tried any clue why and if so how to correct it. Appreciate your help

Comment: @Ranisha If you are using a half-way recent version of GHC it should come with Data.Function, but I have edited my answer to include the definition of `on`.